# Decreasing an ATX PSU voltage using the sense wire?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, atx

I am trying to decrease the voltage of an ATX PSU to about 11.9 volts or so (it's 12.2v, a bit higher than what I would like for my project).

I did read some stuff about using the voltage sense wire with some resistors, but that only works to increase the voltage, not decreasing it. So I had this idea, of actually connecting the 3.3v sense wire to the +5v wire through a high resistor. Do you think this would work? And if so, what kind of pot range would you recommend?

Comment: The problem I see is that you will be dropping different voltages depending on the load current.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see why connecting the 3.3V sense wire will have any affect on the 12V output. All it will do is try to pull the 3.3V output as low as possible, because the sense wire is feeding back 5V which tells the controller that the 3.3V output is over-voltage. It may even shut down the 3.3v output.

You could use a schottky diode in series with the 12V output. A good schottky will drop about 0.4V to give you 11.8V. What current do you need to draw from the power supply? You need to chose a schottky diode that is suitable for the current.

Comment: Schottky is a good idea, but I'm more interested by why .3V matters. If it's that big a problem then chances are this is near the max operating voltage or there's some majorly sensitive circuitry. In either case I'm wondering if he doesn't need an adjustable LDO he can fix at a lower voltage. It will help with transients as well.

Comment: The load is pretty big, about 10A. I need it for some LEDs. Right now, I am using resistors to drop the voltage, but I was thinking of something a bit more efficient.

Comment: @Radu why is it so important that it is 11.9V ? How accurate is your voltmeter? When was it last calibrated?

Comment: It is important because the LEDs will eat a lot more power (and be less efficient) when they are in overdrive. I also checked with my bench PSU, and 11.9V is where they are the happiest. My voltmeter also agrees with the bench PSU.

Comment: Anyway, my line of thinking if that the sense wire senses lower than 3.3v, it will increase the voltage. And maybe, if it sees more, it will lower it. This particular PSU (like most of them) has only a 3.3v sense line, and from reading on other forums, that adjusts all the voltages.

Comment: How many LEDs, series or parallel, are you using a driver, any PWM?

Comment: Both series and parallel, I have 53 LEDs in total. I am not using a driver, I am using the PSU, and if I can get the voltage right, that should be enough. I am playing with some PWM, with a NodeMCU board, and I am getting OK results, but they are not more efficient.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to your sense wire still. According to this... http://www2.mmae.ucf.edu/wiki/ATX_Power_Supply_Mod

That sense wire will not change the 12V line at all but just senses the 3.3V line and keeps your device on. It's essentially an enable and safety measure. If you really want to drop that voltage that's fine, but you're still going to be wasting power with these methods. Just throw it into an LDO, control your output exactly and get the happy 85% general efficiency.

Comment: Yes, it will change the 12v rail (not on all the PSUs, but at least on some). And its role is not just to keep your devices on. It is to adjust the voltage accordingly (see this link) http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?37574-Guide-Power-Supply-Sense-Wire-Modding

Comment: You should be using a current regulator IMHO.

Comment: But I don't need that. The LEDs are very predictable if I give them the right voltage (which I am doing now with some resistors). I just want to make the PSU give me a bit less. Anyway, I guess I will be trying it and see what happens.